# Let $p$ be prime $f(n)=$sum of digits of $n$ in its base $p$ expression. When we have $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is -

> Let $p$ be prime $f(n)=$sum of digits of $n$ in its base $p$
> expression. Prove that, $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$ implies there's no carry
> when base $p$ expressions of $m,n$ are added.

Let, $(m)_p=a_ka_{k-1}\ldots a_1a_0$ and $(n)_p=b_kb_{k-1}\ldots b_1b_0$ i.e. $m=\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i p^i$ and $n=\sum_{i=0}^{k}b_i p^i$.
$f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)$
$\implies f(m+n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}a_i+\sum_{i=0}^{k}b_i$
$\implies f(m+n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(a_i+b_i)$
Again, we have $m+n=\sum_{i=0}(a_i+b_i)p^i$
Now from this, I have to conclude $a_i+b_i\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}\ \forall i\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$. 
I have achieved contradiction by assuming it has only one carry. Can anyone help me complete the proof? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: This is kind of obvious. It is also equivalent to the binomial coefficient $\binom {m+n}m$ not divisible by $p$.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please explain?

Comment: See the first sentence of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Divisibility_properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cliam.** We have $f(m+n)\le f(m)+f(n)$ with equality iff there is no carry.

*Proof.* (Induction on $\max\{n,m\}$). The claim is trivial for $\max\{n,m\}=0$.

In all other cases assume wlog $m\le n$, and we
write $m=pm'+a_0$, $n=pn'+b_0$. Note that this makes $m'\le n'$.

- If $a_0+b_0<p$, then clearly
  $$\begin{align}f(m+n)&=f(m')+a_0+f(n')+b_0\\&=f(m'+n')+a_0+b_0\\&\le f(m')+f(n')+a_0+b_0\\&=f(m)+f(n)\end{align}$$
  with equality iff there is no carry when adding $m'$ and $n'$.
- If $a_0+b_0\ge p$ and $n\le n'+1$, then necessariky $n'=0$ and $n=1$, so $m\le 1$ and so $p=2$. This happens only with
  $$ 1=f(2)=f(1+1)<1+1=f(1)+f(1).$$
- If $a_0+b_0\ge p$ and $n>n'+1$, then
  $$\begin{align}f(m+n)&=f(m'+n'+1)+a_0+b_0-p \\&\le f(m')+f(n')+1+a_0+b_0-p\\&<f(m')+f(n')+a_0+b_0\\&=f(m)+f(n).\end{align}$$

$\square$

Comment: This is awesome. Nice solution.